# Not using grid anywhere still gives error 'cannot use geometry manager pack inside .frame2 which already has slaves managed by grid' in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating this app which works completely and I want to display the output (a pandas dataframe in table and a few matplotlib  graphs) with a little GUI  with tkinter.
Since tkinter doesn't allow grid and pack to work together, I replaced all widgets geometry manager from grid to pack.
It worked fine when I ran the program for first time but since then it has been giving me following error:

```
TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!frame2 which already has slaves managed by grid
```

```
#GUI 

root =  Tk()
root.title('Stocks Analysis')
root.geometry('3000x2400')

var = IntVar()
var.set("1")

imgframe = Frame(root)
imgframe.place(x=0,y=0,relheight=1,relwidth=1)

img = PhotoImage(file = "bgimage.png")
label = Label(imgframe, image = img)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

#mainframe = Frame(root, bgcolor='antique white', height=1400, width=2100, bd=4)
#mainframe.place(relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.25)



analysisframe = Frame(root, bg='antique white', height=1400, width=2100, bd=4)
analysisframe.place(relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.25)


def q():
    root.quit()
    #root.destroy()


def show_analysis():

    pt = Table(analysisframe, dataframe=analysis, width=1200, height=100, 
          editable=False, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
    pt.show()

anbutton = Button(analysisframe, text = "Show Analysis", command = show_analysis())
anbutton.pack()

#infoframe = Label(root, text = "Select from following to display Visual Analysis ", font = 40)
#infoframe.pack()

#Radiobuttons for choosing analysis:

R1 =  Radiobutton(analysisframe, text="Open/Close", variable=var, value=1,
              command=lambda:openclose()).pack()
R2 =  Radiobutton(analysisframe, text="High/Low", variable=var, value=2,
              command=lambda:highlow()).pack()
R3 =  Radiobutton(analysisframe, text="Volume", variable=var, value=3,
              command=lambda:vol()).pack()
R4 =  Radiobutton(analysisframe, text="Simple Moving Average", variable=var, value=4,
              command=lambda:sma()).pack()
R5 =  Radiobutton(analysisframe, text="Bollinger Bands", variable=var, value=5,
              command=lambda:bands()).pack()

quitbutton = Button(analysisframe, text = "QUIT", command = q())
quitbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()

root.destroy()
```

I even tried creating a new Frame but that doesn't work either

Comment: does your `Table` class grid itself in the init method?

Comment: I'm not using OOP for this program so there isn't any class. The data to be displayed is webscraped from the internet, processed and stored in a dataframe 'analysis'. I wanted to display the contents of this dataframe

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] ?

Comment: I would gladly share my script. But I'm new to stackoverflow. Can you tell me how can I share the script with you.

Comment: @VibhuManikpuri copy, paste, format with ``` top and bottom of code (don't indent by 4 spaces)

Comment: Based on your code, the issue is most likely inside `Table(...)` which called `grid()` on widgets created inside `analysisframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `pandas` dataframe, `Table()` should be `pandastable.Table` class which uses `grid()` to layout its components inside its parent (in your case, it is `analysisframe`).  That is why you get the error because you use `pack()` on other widgets in the same frame.

Use another frame for the `pandastable.Table` and use `pack()` on that frame:

```py
def show_analysis():
    # create a frame for the pandastable.Table
    tableframe = Frame(analysisframe)
    tableframe.pack()
    # use tableframe as the parent
    pt = Table(tableframe, dataframe=analysis, width=1200, height=100,
          editable=False, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
    pt.show()
```